# Oracle PL/SQL performance tuning crash course

Tags: oracle, plsql, performance

I am a Java guy who is familiar to basic SQL and PL/SQL.  I can write simple procedures and functions.  Now, I am expected to do some Oracle performance tuning.  Can anyone help me with some crash course material?  Thanks in advance.

--Siddharth

Comment: You can't really do a "crash course" in Oracle performance tuning, any more than you can do a "crash course" in dentistry.  You need to acquire knowledge and experience, and that takes time.

Comment: Some twat has just downvoted every answer below! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know more on SQL preformance tuning, then you need to know the oracle hints and how to check the explain plan of the query:

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/hints/index.html

Other important performance related things are the analytical functions

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/index.html

This can be useful if you are interested more in Oracle Specific options. The other answers might be more useful if you are generally interested in performance tuning

Answer (score 9):

Along with the earlier suggestions (all excellent in their own rights) there are a few simple things you can do which will make you into an Instant Performance Guru (tm):

1. Carry a briefcase full of papers and books.  Dog-eared books with titles like "Oracle Performance Tuning For Highly Effective People"+ and pieces of paper with boxes and arrows scribbled on them work well.  If the books are for outdated versions of Oracle so much the better as it makes it look like you've been doing this for a while - plus, you can buy 'em cheap from the 'clearance' table at your local bookstore.  For best effect the briefcase should be well worn - if you're forced to purchase a new briefcase you can get that weathered effect by backing over it with a car and/or tying a rope to the handle and dragging it through the sand/dirt/mud for ten minutes or so.  This all helps to impress the natives.  A bullet hole or two can be interesting conversation starters.  You can also use the briefcase to carry your lunch and other important stuff like a towel.
2. Add full-key indexes for all queries.
3. Ensure all foreign keys have full-key indexes backing them.

This may give you the idea that "performance analysis" consists mostly of adding the indexes that the people who wrote the software never bothered to add because in their next-to-empty development database everything ran really fast.  This is not correct.  A complete fabrication.  Utter nonsense.  At *best* it's only about, like, 95% of it.  Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain - he is of no importance whatsoever...

You now know the Secrets of the Oracle Performance Masters.  (Well, most of it anyways, except for the Secret Handshake, which is tough to explain in a text message (and besides, you need six fingers on each hand), and the Hidden Mysteries, which consist principally of a lot of stuff about frogs which you don't *technically* need to know but which has been know to make well-informed people giggle a lot - which is not attractive...).

Go ye forth and do ye good works.

+This is actually slightly incorrect.  The book you really want to have in your briefcase is "Oracle Performance Tuning For People Who Are Smarter Than 99.9% Of The Inhabitants Of This Planet".  Since 99.99999%++ of the inhabitants of this planet are single-celled organisms or managers (and sometimes both) this is not difficult to accomplish.

++This is a real number.  You can't just make this stuff up+++.

+++Actually, you can and I did.  But it's not "lying" if you use an exact number - it's "creative re-imagining"++++.

++++That's "lying" in consultant-speak.

Comment: +1 for the humor. Although the advice is a bit simplistic, it IS a good starting point ;-)

Comment: +1 this is being printed right now and being posted on the wall at work

Answer (score 4):

Performance Tuning is all about "It depends". If there existed a check list for how to improve performance, it would already be implemented in the database.

Hang around the OTN forums and look for topics related to tuning. Try to really understand what the experts write. Why was there a problem? What clues was there to aid in discovering a solution? What is the difference in solutions provided? What tradeoffs had to be made in order to select one solution over the other? Re-create the problems in your database and experiment with them yourself.

Don't be afraid to ask if you don't understand why some adviced was posted!

Links to the forums

[SQL and PLSQL- Forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=75)

[General - Forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=61)

Oh, and please don't go down the usual path which is throwing hints at queries until something happens. Without a solid understanding of access statistics, selectivity, costing, join mechanisms, access paths or just basic knowledge of the architecture of the database, it makes no sense whatsoever to override the optimizer with hints.

If I could travel back in time and give myself three books, I would bring:

- Expert Oracle Database Architecture (Tom Kyte)
- Cost-based Oracle Fundamentals (Jonathan Lewis)
- SQL Tuning (Dan Tow)

Answer (score 2):

Two Tom Kyte books:

"Expert Oracle Database Architecture" - A crash course in Oracle internals from the perspective of a developer.

"Effective Oracle by Design" - How to write hi-performance applications. Demystification of tools like EXPLAIN PLAN, AUTOTRACE, TKPROF, Statspack, and DBMS_PROFILER; understanding the optimizer; schema design, and many more.

Any other materials written by Mr. Kyte are worth reading as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [Introduction to Performance Tuning](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/perf_overview.htm#i1005792) section of the Oracle docs.  I have linked to the Oracle 10G version.

Learning to generate and interpret [trace files](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#i4640) might be a good way to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try statspack. Check details [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Statspack)
Performance is usually a black magic and it requires a lot of patience :)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But any good material that can give me at least a launch pad?  Surfing online has confused me a bit.