# How to find all child ids given a parent in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, connect-by

I have a table of ids which have a parentid in a different table and this builds a folder structure in the application layer. I need to get a list of all of the ids in a specific "Root Folder"

```
select count(id)
from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.id
connect by prior t1.id = t2.parentid
start with t1.id in (select id from t3 where name = 'Root Folder')
```

> **t1** = 4,102,065 rows
>
> **t2** = 48,965,392 rows
>
> **t3** is a view
>
> **t4** is the underlying table where the name in t3 is stored (only referenced in the explain plan below)

Right now this is returning the correct results, but taking 3m41s (count is 3,257,847)

Is there a better way to do this type of query or are my only options indexes?

Here is the explain plan, I've replaced the real table and index names to match my example above:

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 14  Bytes: 20  Cardinality: 1                                   
17 SORT GROUP BY  Bytes: 20  Cardinality: 1                                 
    16 CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING                            
        10 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 5  Bytes: 153  Cardinality: 3                        
            8 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 4  Bytes: 27  Cardinality: 1                      
                6 VIEW VIEW SYS.VW_NSO_1 Cost: 2  Bytes: 10  Cardinality: 1                 
                    5 HASH UNIQUE  Bytes: 57  Cardinality: 1            
                        4 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 2  Bytes: 57  Cardinality: 1          
                            2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE T2 Cost: 1  Bytes: 40  Cardinality: 1   
                                1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX T2_NAME Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1  
                            3 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) T3_ID Cost: 1  Bytes: 17  Cardinality: 1     
                7 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) T1_ID Cost: 1  Bytes: 17  Cardinality: 1                 
            9 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX T2_ID_PARENTID Cost: 1  Bytes: 72  Cardinality: 3                      
        15 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 7  Bytes: 867  Cardinality: 17                       
            13 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 6  Bytes: 1,292  Cardinality: 38                     
                11 CONNECT BY PUMP                  
                12 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX T2_PARENTID_ID Cost: 1  Bytes: 312  Cardinality: 13               
            14 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) T1_ID Cost: 1  Bytes: 17  Cardinality: 1
```

Comment: An explain plan may help us understand the issue.  Run `explain plan for select count(id) ...` to generate the plan, and then run this to display the plan: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Print the entire output here.

Comment: From the tone of your last sentence it appears you may indexes are a bad idea. Why would that be?

Comment: You query is simple, try using query hints with index

Comment: @jon-heller I've added the explain plan.

Comment: @bob-jarvis no, not at all, just that I want to get it performing as best as I can before I have to ask the DBA to create indexes

Comment: The addition of indexes will (hopefully) change the query plan completely, thus negating any work you may have done to improve the performance without using indexes. [Also see my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142790/oracle-pl-sql-performance-tuning-crash-course/4144692#4144692). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to create indexes on t1.id  and t2.parentid and to ensure that those indexes are used by analyze the execution plan and use hints if it is the case. Also take care to have fresh performance statistcs for t1, t2 and it's indexes.